# CSS Container margin bottom issue

Tags: html, css

Hi for mobile version I need margin bottom (white space from bottom of the screen) to the container, it was not working. I have tried position absolute still it was not working. I don't know what mistake exactly I did in here.

```
 ****Desktop version CSS****
       #container {
       width: 70%;
       margin: 0 auto;
       display: flex;
       height: 100vh;
       align-items: center;
```

}

```
****mobile version CSS****
 `     #container {
       display: block;
       text-align: center;
       margin-bottom:25px;  
}
```

Comment: Use `padding-bottom` instead of margin

Comment: yeah tried these still not working. Padding top and margin top works fine. Still Padding bottom and margin bottom not working.

Comment: can you create the jssnipped?

Answer (score 0):

```
****mobile version CSS****
 `     #container {
       display: block;
       text-align: center;
       margin-bottom:25px !important;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            test content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And use these styles:

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: red;
}
#container {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media(min-width:480px) {
    #container {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
@media(max-width:480px) {
    #container {
        height: calc(100% - 30px);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute;` and set `top` `left` `right` `bottom` to `0`, then `bottom: 25px` for mobile version:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  .item {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```